# SSRS 2012 Reporting Services parallel dataset retrieval

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to optimize a report for SSRS 2012 and using SQL Profiler I can see that the datasets are being processed one at a time instead of in parallel.
The checkbox to request one transaction is NOT checked.
I can't find any other setting on parallel execution.
The data source is an embedded data source.

Every item I find on the internet about parallel execution quotes a Microsoft BLOG from about a decade ago that states 2008 defaulted to parallel unless that single transaction box is checked, and the assumption is that nothing ever changes so this is still default behavior.

It would appear that the box has a different purpose since running in one transaction allows a temp table created in one dataset to be referenced in a later dataset - they are not only serialized but processed in their listed order (top to bottom).  So that is about persistence of objects and data instead of parallel vs serialized.

Without the box checked it appears they are called in the order the fields are processed, but profiler results indicate that only one dataset is retrieved at a time.

So, is there a verified way to fetch multiple datasets simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there aren't any other settings to control this behavior besides the one you described. Of course there are always other ways around this if efficiency is an issue for you. For example, you could look into caching the results before the report runs.

Comment: thanks.   I was running the report via Visual Studio 2013 and that may have forced it to run them sequentially - the trace against the report server ran a stored procedure in parallel but all the other datasets were serialized.  I think I would have to use some sub-reports (which are callbacks) or somehow cache the datasets that are not specific to the requested factory order to boost the speed.